# Efficient algorithm for mapping a fraction to an integer

Tags: c, performance, algorithm

I have a `float`, `f`, in the range 1 to 0 that I want to map to an `int`, `i`. `f` is related to `i` by:

```
f = 1/(2^i)
```

so

```
i = log2(1/f)
```

I'm using the following to calculate `i`:

```
int i = log2f(floorf(1/f));
```

This expression involves 3 float operations so I assume it is relatively inefficient.

My questions:

1. Generally speaking, is this inefficient? (I appreciate that this is a difficult to answer due to platform dependent optimisations)
2. Is it possible to create a more efficient algorithm? Seeing as this involves `2^n` I guess that a more efficient algorithm could be created using `int`s and bit shifting.

Comment: Why flooring twice? Why not i = log2f(1/f) ?

Comment: When "Relative speaking", what is it relative to?  A floating point log function on an embedded system that does not have an FPU is very slow when compared to an integer subtraction, but on a modern desktop, it will be much faster than opening a file.

Comment: @StephenNutt Good point. I've changed the phrase to "generally speaking".

Comment: There could be significant performance optimizations made, but they all require a narrowing of the problem scope.  If this for a single CPU architecture, what precision do you need and is there a range limit for i and f?  As for question 1, with no idea of how frequently this operation is being performed, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: you could use [frexpf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/frexp.html)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `f` is positive, `log2(1/f)` is equivalent to `-log2(f)`, which should let you simplify a bit:

```
int i=floorf(-log2f(f));
```

Substituting negation for division may help speed quite a bit.

If you don't mind some thoroughly non-portable code, you should be able to extract the exponent part of your floating point number directly. A good implementation of `log2f` will probably already do that though, so you may be giving up portability for little or nothing in return.

Answer (score 2):

You should find out how float is stored. In a typical machine that uses 4 bytes to store float, last 1 byte is used to store binary exponential. If you can access that part of the memory, then you are almost done.

Eg. In C you can declare a union structure to store 1 float or 4 short unsigned int (1 byte/ short int). All you have to do is assign the float and extract the short int that stores the  exponential).

The actual values mentioned in this answer may be incorrect on your machine, but you can use this approach if you know the right numbers.

Comment: `short int` is always at least 2 bytes - perhaps you meant `int8_t`?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft  In 1999 when I was using C on my pentium II machines, short int was 1 byte :D As I mentioned, I am not sure about the numbers, but using union is the way to go here.

Comment: `short` has *always* been required to be at least two bytes *(at least, as far back as C89)*.  Either you had an extremely bad compiler, or your memory is incorrect.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Or, probably it was unsigned char.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I got this straight. For f=0.5, 1/f = 2, so you want i to be 1. For any f larger than 0.5, 1/f will be less than 2, so i will be 0, right?

```
For 0.5<f<=1     i=0
For 0.25<f<0.5   i=1
For 0.125<f<0.25 i=2
and so on.
```

So i is basically the zero-based index of the first 1 bit of the mantissa (taking into account the exponent, which should be added to it)

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's assume that your floating point follows IEEE754 standard, and that the values are correctly calculated. (It's possible to represent your values correctly as `float`, because the `f` is always a power of two.)

Looking at the IEEE754 standard, your number `f` will always* have mantissa 1.0, so what you really need is to extract the exponent. This can be done by using the binary representation of `float`: the number is itself 32-bit, and the exponent us located at bits 24-31 (counting from right to left). You'll need to subtract 127 from the value.

See, for example, this [online converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) and any documentation on IEEE754 standard for more details.

---

*Well, except denormalized cases. Denormalized float is one that is stored not like `1*2^-2`, but rather like `0.5*2^-1`. For handling the denormalized floats I would recommend converting them to normalized ones by adding 0.0. You can easily detect denormalized floats by mantissa being not 1 in your case.

Answer (score 1):

C has a function for this purpose: frexpf (1999 C standard section 7.12.6.4). It normalizes so the exponent matches a fraction in [1/2, 1), so you will need to subtract 1 from its exponent (e.g., for .25f, it gives an exponent of -1, since .25f = .5 * 2<sup>-1</sup>, but you want -2):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int exponent;
    for (float f = 0x1p-149f; f <= 1; f += f)
    {
        frexpf(f, &exponent);
        printf("The exponent of %a is %d.\n", f, exponent-1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```